# The field Valor Pago must be a number. ASP NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Eu possuo este campo na Model:

```
public decimal Valor { get; set; }
```

Ele grava corretamente, e me mostra o valor desta forma:

> 10,00

Porém quando eu vou editar, e concluir a ação, ele me retorna :

> The field Valor Pago must be a number.

Tentei adicionar este script que vi em um tutorial para verificar se resolvia o problema, porém ainda persiste:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
   date: function (value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || /^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d?\d?$/.test(value);
   },
   number: function (value, element)  
      return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+)(?:,\d+)?$/.test(value);
   }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
   <label asp-for="ContasReceberVM.ContasReceber.Valor" class="control-label"></label>
   <input asp-for="ContasReceberVM.ContasReceber.Valor" class="form-control" type="text" />
   <span asp-validation-for="ContasReceberVM.ContasReceber.Valor" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ficar copiando código assim da net e colocá-lo para funcionar no seu código, sem saber o que realmente o código está fazendo, definitivamente não é uma boa prática. Por exemplo  vc viu que este código está com um fechamento de chaves a mais?

Comment: É porque tinha colocado dentro de uma função pra ver se o problema podia ser ser, mas de todas as formas não funcionou. Eu sei que não é uma boa prática, mas nenhuma forma funciona, então eu tenho que arriscar com códigos da internet.

Comment: Vc sabe que isto é um plugin, não sabe?

Comment: Sei sim, porém ele não deu certo. tentei tipo uma máscara e não da certo, eu não consegui nem tipo converter, porque na hora que clica no button, ele já retorna este erro.

Comment: Poste a sua model inteira